# Stopwatch different timing why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am using a stopwatch start and stop in order to find out the time of process of a web service how ever when I refresh the page in order to do another test using the same parameters, data an all but the second and all the other test bring back different results. But when I restart the IIS server it again shows the initial result.

So my question is why do I receive a different result in time the first time?

By the way I wrote the web service in C#.

Comment: Define "different results".  Faster?  Slower?   (most likely it's faster and you are seeing the benefits of the jitter and various sorts of caching in the VM.  you should not measure the performance of something the first time -- throw those results away and focus on subsequent refreshes)

Comment: @KirkWoll as you say i recive faster result, let say my fist test takes around 30 sec, the next time using the same data the time is reduce to 5 sec, this is what i dont understan why the second time is faster and fist is slower?

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting this question?

Comment: Surprised on this question getting down votes. IMO its a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why it's much slower the first time, consider what has to happen the first time:

1. Assemblies must be loaded from disk.
2. The code will be jitted, which means that it must be translated from IL to machine code.
3. The pages (.cshtml/.aspx) must be parsed.  Once parsed, their compiled representation is stored in memory and immediately available upon subsequent requests.

Generally speaking, none of that has to happen the second time you load the page.  There are potentially countless other things that happen the first time and are then cached.  This is why subsequent refreshes will usually be much faster.

Comment: I gave you the +1 because you took the time to answer a question that others brushed off. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer this was the answer that i was looking for i have no idea that all the 3 ponit you mention was goin on